# How do I host my API 2 project externally?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-web-api2

I have a functioning API that I can launch from Visual Studio 2015, I can also clean and build it.  It outputs a dll file with other supporting files but I don't understand how I take the build files and actually host them as an API.

How can I host my API 2 project externally?

Comment: I have no idea where I can ask this question, where to look, or even how to begin looking.  For the love of Buddha someone please help me.  Every answer I see says "launch from inside Visual Studio, it works, good job."

Comment: This is too broad a question for Stack Overflow. Try coming up with specific questions regarding APIs, something you can show any code attempts you've made.

Comment: The question is specific though, how in the name of Buddha do a launch my API outside of Visual Studio.  And there isn't anything to do with code, the point is I built it and the API itself already works.

Comment: Thank you Soviut for helping me.

Comment: No problem. That's a much clearer question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like most Microsoft web technologies, you'll most likely have to host them on a web server running IIS.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/how-to-host-Asp-Net-web-api-on-iis-server/

Visual Studio has a wizard for publishing API services to IIS.

http://dotnetmentors.com/web-api/host-asp-net-web-api-in-iis-using-visual-studio-publish.aspx

If you don't have an IIS web server, you can host on the Microsoft Azure cloud platform which will provide an instance of IIS for you.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-10